# Для чего xmlns:app и xmlns:tools ? И обязательны ли они?

Tags: android, android-layout

Видел как некоторые разработчики удаляют эти строки из layout файла, хотя они появляются изначально по умолчанию. Так что, стоит ли удалять их, раз они не выпоняют важной роли в проекте ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xmlns:app` нужен для обозначения кастомных свойст `View`. `xmlns:tools` - позволяет среде разработки (в нашем случае, Android Studio) правильно отобразить компоненты для просмотра в режиме дизайна.

[Подробнее про tools](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/studio/tools.php)

[Подробнее про app](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-xmlns-app-and-xmlns-Android)

Comment: значит, они обязательны ?

Comment: @OlegKhegay нет. Если у вас нет кастомных атрибутов, то app можно не использовать. Вам сама студия это покажет. Tools также необязательный параметр